# What is wrong with my implementation of simulated annealing?

Tags: optimization, octave, simulated-annealing

I have written implemenation of simulated annealing in Octave and even tough I have tried to change every parameter I can't get this method to find the global minimum which is the usage of this algorithm. Please, help me find what is the problem here.

```
clear;
clc;

T = 10000; 
L = 10000; 
r = 100; 
a = 0.95;

function y = f(x1, x2)
  y = -(x2 + 47).*sin(sqrt(abs(x1./2+(x2+47)))) - x1.*sin(sqrt(abs(x1-(x2+47))));
end

x0 = -512+rand(1, 2)*1024;

fl = [];
x = [];
y = [];

for i = 0:L
  x1 = [-1000 1000]
  while (x1(1) > 512 || x1(1) < -512) || (x1(2) > 512 || x1(2) < -512) 
    x1 = x0 + r*(2*rand(1,2)-1)*sqrt(T); 
  end
  df = f(x1(1), x1(2)) - f(x0(1), x0(2)); 
  if df < 0
    x0 = x1;
  elseif rand() < exp(-df/T)
    x0 = x1;
  endif
  T = a*T;
  fl = [fl; f(x0(1), x0(2))];
  x = [x; x0(1)];
  y = [y; x0(2)];
endfor

figure;
plot(0:L,fl);

figure;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(-512:.5:512);
Z = -(Y + 47).*sin(sqrt(abs(X./2+(Y+47)))) - X.*sin(sqrt(abs(X-(Y+47))));
contour(X, Y, Z);

hold on;

plot(x, y, 'k', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

Comment: Did you step through the algorithm in the debugger?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, everything seems to be fine expect of course for the final result. The algorithm finds minimum but not the global one. For like 50 tries it found the right result only once but it is told that it should find it at least 4 times per 5 tries.

Comment: Your step size go down way to quickly, for most of your steps (more than 80%) the difference between x1 and x0 is 0. 

You add or subtract values in the magnitude of `r*sqrt(T)` which is `4.044717991929277e-108` after the last iteration. It might be a good idea to normalize your annealing and have both the first step size and final step size as a parameter. This makes it easy to keep it in the relevant range.

Comment: And even if you don't change your math to have these two parameters, print `r*sqrt(T)` in the first and last step. It should start somewhere around 512. A reasonable choice for your final step is by a factor of 10 to 100 smaller than your intended precision.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for your reply. It works better now but it's still around 50% success rate.

Comment: Could you update your question and add the code you are now using below the original question?